# SAS IF Condition data retrieval

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, sas, nested-if

I have a dataset that has many fields out of the 7 needed fields for this condition is

- status_reason_code_1
- status_reason_code_1_date
- status_reason_code_2
- status_reason_code_2_date
- status_reason_code_3
- status_reason_code_3_date
- charge_date

So, I need to check whether either of **status_reason_code_1** OR **status_reason_code_2** OR **status_reason_code_3** is having a value of **'68'**, then we need to pick up the associated **status_reason_code_dt** i.e. if **status_reason_code_1** is **68** I need to retrive the s**tatus_reason_code_1_date** . Then If **status_reason_code_1_date** is equal to or less than **charge_date** then set a value of **'Y'** OR else **'N'**.

How do I code this in SAS ? How to retrieve the associated date and do the rest of the comparison? When status_reason_code_1 is associated with Status_reason_Code_1_date

I need the code something like this .

''''DATA test1;
SET test2;
IF status_reason_code_1 = '68' OR status_reason_code_2 = '68' OR status_reason_code_3 = '68'
--> Here if status_reason_code_1 is equal to 68 then we should take status_reason_code_1_date and compare it with charge_date. Need a nested if condition here
IF status_reason_code_1_date <= charge_date
THEN flag = 'Y' ELSE flag='N''''

Comment: Please update your question to include some example data (i.e. DATA step with CARDS statement for 5 records), and also show the desired output from that data.  Also add the code you have tried.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "retrieve".  Do you just mean you want to compare the value of the two DATE variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So define two arrays for the two groups of 3 variables.  Loop over them checking for the 68 and then date until you either finish the list or find your condition.

```
data want;
   set have;
   array code status_reason_code_1-status_reason_code_3 ;
   array date status_reason_code_1_date status_reason_code_2_date status_reason_code_3_date ;
   found='N';
   do index=1 to 3 until(found='Y') ;
      if code[index]='68' and .Z < date[index] <= charge_date then found='Y';
   end;
   drop index;
run;
```

NOTE: Notice how the DATE series of variable names is harder to work with.  That is because you placed the numeric sequence number in the MIDDLE of the variable name instead of at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you please explain why you have used the .Z here.  I understand in the section date[index] refers to the status_reason_code_1_date but what does the first part of the code  .z <= DTAE[INDEX]

Comment: SAS has 28 ways to store missing values. All of them are less than any actual number. 
 And  .Z is the largest of them.  So using `.Z < date <= cutoff` will exclude all possible missing values from being included. And it takes less typing then coding something like  `date <= cutoff and not missing(date)`